# How can I return a list having the following sum v[i]=A[i,2i]+A[i,2i+1]

Tags: python

A is a matrix of size nx2n ,and I'm trying to write a Python code that will return the list v without using a for loop using numpy functions.

Comment: This question is better suited for stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

`li = [A[i][2*i] + A[i][2*i + 1] for i in range(n)]`

Comment: This will return the list ?

Comment: @user3133165 yes, `li` is the required list

Comment: This uses a `for` loop inside the list comprehension though

Comment: Is there a solution using numpy twithout having to use any for ?

Comment: @user3133165 I can't say for sure. You should ask on Stack Overflow. Also, even if you do get such a method, it might internally use `for` or its equivalent